# How to compare the distance of every row from each other using lat long in Spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data that looks like this:

```
name | Lat | long |
A    | 1.0 | 20.0 |
B    | 2.1 | 21.0 |
C    | 3.0 | 22.0 |
D    | 4.0 | 23.0 |
```

*these are just sample data.

I need to know what is the distance of the column "name" from each other using their lat-long

Now, I found the formula on how to get the distance using lat-long, but now I need to determine which is my end lat-long and my start lat-long to compare the distance, to get this I have to generate a result like this:

```
startName |startLat | startLong | endName | EndLat | endLong |
    A     | 1.0     | 20.0      |     B   |  2.1   | 21.0    |
    A     | 1.0     | 20.0      |     C   |  3.0   | 22.0    |
    A     | 1.0     | 20.0      |     D   |  4.0   | 23.0    | 
    B     | 2.1     | 21.0      |     A   |  1.0   | 20.0    |
    B     | 2.1     | 21.0      |     C   |  3.0   | 22.0    |
    B     | 2.1     | 21.0      |     D   |  4.0   | 23.0    |
```

Question is, how can I generate this output using spark-scala?

Or, any suggestion for an easier way to get the distance aside from this, would be really helpful.

Comment: What's your concern with the existing solution ?
Check Apache Sedona for geospatial analytics.

Comment: @gatear I'm not sure how to generate the second result(the one with startName) using the original data (the one with column "Name")

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output rename some columns then join everything.
You probably need to avoid records with the same start end.

```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val input: DataFrame =
    ???
    
  val start: DataFrame =
    input.select(
      col("name") as "startName",
      col("lat") as "startLat",
      col("long") as "startLong"
    )

  val end: DataFrame =
    input.select(
      col("name") as "endName",
      col("lat") as "endLat",
      col("long") as "endLong"
    )

  start.join(end, col("startName") =!= col("endName"))
```